# I have committed major sin of adultry, am i still forgivable if i ask forgiveness

Tags: allah, punishment, forgiveness, masturbation, akhirah

ASALAMUALAKUM my name is rehan and i am 15 years old for the past 7 months i have been online schooling but i have been engaged in porn first but then i started being engaged in masturbation i have been doing it for months and i cannot talk to anyone else about it because i am too shameful to talk about it but few days ago i learned that it is a major sin and i am very scared cause i am afraid there are punishments for it as well please tell me are there any? But i want to ask forgiveness from Allah now please tell me if i stop doing it and promise not to do it again and ask forgiveness can i still be forgiven from Allah?

Comment: Where does adultery come in to place here?

Comment: Well just tell me can i be forgiven or not i am in deep stress!

Comment: you’ve already gotten your question answered and this question has been answered numerous times.

Comment: A yes or no will do you know

Comment: did you read Firdou Mala’s answer? He/she said yes.

Answer (score 1):

وعلیکم السلام

---

Haven't you heard the story of the one who was forgiven even after killing a hundred people!

Allah (swt) forgives all sins as long as one repents.

Comment: so even masturbation?

Comment: Please respond brother

Comment: Yes, even this act is forgivable.

Comment: Thank you brother

Comment: May Allah forgive us all ameen❤